# Subgame equilibrium of Rubinstein bargaining with alternating offers

Tags: game-theory

In class, we learned that there is a unique subgame perfect Nash equilibrium for the infinite Rubinstein bargaining with alternating offers (and some discount factor).
My question is: Why is it not a perfect subgame equilibrium if

- Player 1 always asks for the entire money and rejects every offer
- Player 2 always asks for the entire money and rejects every offer

Then both players would receive $0$ but if only one player changed his strategy, he couldn't do better since the other player would reject every proposal.

Answer (score 0):

For it to be a subgame perfect Nash equilibrium, you need a Nash equilibrium in every subgame. If you look at the subgame right after P1 makes a positive offer, P2 chooses between accepting or rejecting. Rejecting gives him $0$, since both players are playing a "always reject" strategy. Accepting means getting some positive amount. So this subgame is not in Nash equilibrium.

You're correct that no player has an incentive to deviate unilaterally - so your strategy profile is a Nash equilibrium, just not a subgame perfect Nash equilibrium.

Comment: In my strategy both players demand everything for themselves in every offer. So P2 would get 0 by accepting if I‘m not mistaken.

Comment: Yes that's true for that one subgame where P1 demands everything. But remember we need Nash equilibrium in **every subgame** (even in situations not reached). So there is a subgame where P1 offers, say, 0.8. In this case, then P2 playing reject isn't optimal, because this would eventually yield them 0, whereas accepting yields them a payoff of 0.2.

Comment: I should point out that your strategy profile of both players playing "always ask for everything and reject all offers" is a Nash equilibrium, because you're right that no matter how each player deviates, they can't yield a better payoff. It's just not a subgame perfect Nash equilibrium.

Comment: But here each subgame is essentially just a copy of the original game (maybe with reversed order of P1 and P2).

Comment: In our definition players don‘t change their strategies in subgames. So P1 would never offer 0.8?

Comment: Do you have a reference for a rigorous defintion of subgame perfect nash equilibrium?

Comment: Actually, there are more subgames than what you're thinking. Think about the game tree for this game. P1 can play any $x \in [0,1]$, so you can imagine an infinite number of actions from the first node. Under each of these actions is a subgame where P2 has to accept or reject an offer of $x$, where P2 will receive $1-x$. A SPNE requires that every single one of these subgames be in Nash equilibrium (not just the one where $x=1$).

Comment: You could refer to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subgame_perfect_equilibrium) or pg. 95 of the [Gibbons textbook](https://sites.math.rutgers.edu/~zeilberg/EM22/gibbons.pdf)